# Как изменять цвет пикселей картинки?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

хочу написать программу которое сделал бы blur effect используя `QPixmap`, `QImage`

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
import sys

def main():    
    app     = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window  = QMainWindow() 
    label   = QLabel(window) 
    pixmap = QPixmap('myimage.gif')
    label.setPixmap(pixmap)
    window.setCentralWidget(label)
    window.setWindowTitle("Blur Effect Example")
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

как мне изменить цвета пикселей pixmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляем кнопку на панель инструментов по нажатию на которую будет в случайном месте со случайным цветом создаваться квадрат 20x20:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QMainWindow()
label = QLabel()
pixmap = QPixmap(label.size())
pixmap.fill(Qt.transparent)

label.setPixmap(pixmap)

window.setCentralWidget(label)
window.setWindowTitle("Blur Effect Example")

def draw_random():
    painter = QPainter(label.pixmap())
    # or:
    # painter = QPainter(pixmap)

    painter.setBrush(QColor(randint(0, 0xFF), randint(0, 0xFF), randint(0, 0xFF)))

    x, y = randint(0, pixmap.width()), randint(0, pixmap.height())
    painter.drawRect(x, y, 20, 20)
    
    label.update()
    # or:
    # label.setPixmap(pixmap)

general_tool_bar = window.addToolBar('General')
action = general_tool_bar.addAction('Draw Rand Rect')
action.triggered.connect(draw_random)

window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]